# There's some way to change the display of options from select to looks like a button?

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I'm working to make options of a select looks like a button, but I don't have any clue of how to do this or even if this could be done.

It need to be a select (or something like that, with the nest elements) cause the way that platform works, I can't change this. I already tried use two buttons, no work at all. 
Here's the code that i'm using to make the select:

```
<select class="form-control cc-skuDropdown"
    data-bind="validatableTarget: selectedOption, 
    validationOptions: {decorateElement: false, decorateElementOnModified:  false}, options: optionValues, 
    optionsText: 'key', attr: {id: 'CC-prodDetails-' + $data.optionId}, optionsCaption: $data.optionCaption, 
    value: $data.selectedOption, disable: $parent.disableOptions() || $data.disable">
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MDN: [Introduction to CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS)

Comment: Hi Mateus, I have just made a similar feature for tablet sized screens to replace dropdowns with modals containing buttons (eventually doing the exact same). It is possible just by plainly removing the select and instead of using options, using button elements. I will see if I could provide you with some example code.

Comment: Here's what I coded. The button appear and work fine with the radio, but not work properly with the back-end cause the system miss the "options"
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WmWWMa

Comment: If it is only HTML, CSS and JavaScript you are looking for, you could do something along the lines of this: https://jsfiddle.net/doLjx320/ Please let me know if this is what you are looking for so I could elaborate an answer.

Comment: Updated link with explanation: https://jsfiddle.net/fhpcryv6/1/

Comment: There's some way to make the buttons appear without the need to click on the trigger?
Also, I could use any solution that make this happen.

Comment: I'm looking to the code to keep the buttons open without the trigger.

Comment: Just remove the `hidden` class from related elements and any javascript functionality related to it @MateusFernando https://jsfiddle.net/eLbd7pof/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190753/discussion-between-barrosy-and-mateus-fernando).